# How do I pass values between cards in Java CardLayout

Tags: java, swing, cardlayout

//This is my main function:

```
public class MainPane {

    private JPanel contentPane;
    private Login p1;
    private Main p2;
    public String S1;

    public void displayGUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Card Layout Example");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);            
        JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();
        //a=S1;            
        contentPane.setLayout(new CardLayout());            
        p1 = new Login(contentPane);
        p2 = new Main(contentPane);            
        contentPane.add(p1, "Panel 1");
        contentPane.add(p2, "Panel 2");            
        frame.setContentPane(contentPane);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        System.out.println("Mainpane");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                new MainPane().displayGUI();
            }
        }            
        );
    }
}
```

this is the first card

```
public class Login extends javax.swing.JPanel{

    private JPanel contentpane;
    private String phn;
    static final String JDBC_Driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    static final String DB_URL="jdbc:mysql://localhost/medicine";
    static final String USER="root";
    static final String PASS="";
    public String name;

    /**
     * Creates new form Login
     */
    public Login(JPanel cp) {

        System.out.println("Login1");
        this.contentpane=cp;
        initComponents();
        currectdata();
        jPanel3.setVisible(false);
        jPanel2.setVisible(false);
    }

    public void currectdata(){
        Calendar cal=new GregorianCalendar();
        int month=cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int year=cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int day=cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        int am=cal.get(Calendar.AM_PM);
        int second=cal.get(Calendar.SECOND);
        int minute=cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        int hour=cal.get(Calendar.HOUR);
        jLabel17.setText(month+"/"+day+"/"+year);
        if(am==0)jLabel18.setText(hour+":"+minute+" AM");
        else jLabel18.setText(hour+":"+minute+" PM");
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLayeredPane2 = new javax.swing.JLayeredPane();
        jPanel2 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jLabel8 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel9 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jButton4 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jPasswordField2 = new javax.swing.JPasswordField();
        jPasswordField3 = new javax.swing.JPasswordField();
        jButton5 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jComboBox1 = new javax.swing.JComboBox();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jPasswordField1 = new javax.swing.JPasswordField();
        jLabel5 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel6 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jPanel3 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jTextField4 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel7 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jTextField2 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton3 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jPanel4 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jLabel10 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel11 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel12 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel13 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel14 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel15 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel16 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel17 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel18 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        setBackground(new java.awt.Color(204, 204, 255));
        setLayout(new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteLayout());

        jLabel3.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Comic Sans MS", 1, 36)); // NOI18N
        jLabel3.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 153));
        jLabel3.setText("SSS'S DISPENSARY");
        add(jLabel3, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(494, 45, -1, 81));

        jLayeredPane2.setLayout(new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteLayout());

        jPanel2.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(null, "CHANGE PASSWORD", javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.DEFAULT_JUSTIFICATION, javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.DEFAULT_POSITION, new java.awt.Font("Comic Sans MS", 1, 24), new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 153))); // NOI18N
        jPanel2.setLayout(new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteLayout());

        jLabel8.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Comic Sans MS", 1, 18)); // NOI18N
        jLabel8.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 153));
        jLabel8.setText("NEW PASSWORD:");
        jPanel2.add(jLabel8, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(138, 132, -1, -1));

        jLabel9.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Comic Sans MS", 1, 18)); // NOI18N
        jLabel9.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 153));
        jLabel9.setText("CONFIRM PASSWORD:");
        jPanel2.add(jLabel9, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(94, 194, -1, -1));

        jButton4.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Comic Sans MS", 1, 18)); // NOI18N
        jButton4.setText("CHANGE");
        jButton4.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton4ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        jPanel2.add(jButton4, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(403, 303, -1, -1));

        jPasswordField2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Comic Sans MS", 1, 18)); // NOI18N
        jPanel2.add(jPasswordField2, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(334, 129, 211, -1));

        jPasswordField3.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Comic Sans MS", 1, 18)); // NOI18N
        jPanel2.add(jPasswordField3, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(334, 191, 211, -1));

        jButton5.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Comic Sans MS", 1, 18)); // NOI18N
        jButton5.setText("BACK");
        jButton5.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton5ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        jPanel2.add(jButton5, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(138, 303, 98, -1));

        jLayeredPane2.add(jPanel2, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(0, 0, 640, 420));

        jPanel1.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(null, "LOGIN", javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.DEFAULT_JUSTIFICATION, javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.DEFAULT_POSITION, new java.awt.Font("Comic Sans MS", 1, 24), new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 153))); // NOI18N
        jPanel1.setLayout(new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteLayout());

        jLabel1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Comic Sans MS", 1, 18)); // NOI18N
        jLabel1.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 153));
        jLabel1.setText("USERNAME:");
        jPanel1.add(jLabel1, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(97, 110, -1, -1));

        jTextField1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Comic Sans MS", 1, 18)); // NOI18N
        jPanel1.add(jTextField1, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(253, 107, 246, -1));

        jLabel2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Comic Sans MS", 1, 18)); // NOI18N
        jLabel2.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 153));
        jLabel2.setText("PASSWORD:");
        jPanel1.add(jLabel2, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(95, 160, -1, -1));

        jComboBox1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Comic Sans MS", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
        jComboBox1.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] { "CEO", "REGULAR EMPLOYEE" }));
        jPanel1.add(jComboBox1, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(253, 207, 246, -1));

        jButton1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Comic Sans MS", 1, 18)); // NOI18N
        jButton1.setText("LOGIN");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        jPanel1.add(jButton1, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(253, 305, -1, -1));

        jPasswordField1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Comic Sans MS", 1, 18)); // NOI18N
        jPanel1.add(jPasswordField1, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(253, 157, 246, -1));

        jLabel5.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Comic Sans MS", 1, 18)); // NOI18N
        jLabel5.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 153));
        jLabel5.setText("LOGIN AS:");
        jPanel1.add(jLabel5, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(106, 210, -1, -1));

        jLabel6.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 2, 12)); // NOI18N
        jLabel6.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 0, 0));
        jLabel6.setText("Forgot Password?");
        jLabel6.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                jLabel6MouseClicked(evt);
            }
        });
        jPanel1.add(jLabel6, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(253, 272, 115, -1));

        jLayeredPane2.add(jPanel1, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(0, 0, 640, 420));

        jPanel3.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(null, "VERIFICATION", javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.DEFAULT_JUSTIFICATION, javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.DEFAULT_POSITION, new java.awt.Font("Comic Sans MS", 1, 24), new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 153))); // NOI18N
        jPanel3.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(645, 423));
        jPanel3.setLayout(new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteLayout());
        jPanel3.add(jTextField4, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(190, 170, 150, -1));

        jLabel4.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\sakib\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\New_Dispensary\\src\\new_dispensary\\CAPTCHA.jpg")); // NOI18N
        jPanel3.add(jLabel4, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(170, 80, -1, -1));

        jLabel7.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Comic Sans MS", 1, 18)); // NOI18N
        jLabel7.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 153));
        jLabel7.setText("PHONE NO:");
        jPanel3.add(jLabel7, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(129, 250, 110, 30));

        jTextField2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Comic Sans MS", 1, 18)); // NOI18N
        jPanel3.add(jTextField2, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(275, 250, 220, 30));

        jButton2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Comic Sans MS", 1, 18)); // NOI18N
        jButton2.setText("SUBMIT");
        jButton2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton2ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        jPanel3.add(jButton2, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(413, 320, 110, 30));

        jButton3.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Comic Sans MS", 1, 18)); // NOI18N
        jButton3.setText("BACK");
        jButton3.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(107, 35));
        jButton3.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton3ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        jPanel3.add(jButton3, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(129, 320, 120, 30));

        jLayeredPane2.add(jPanel3, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(0, 0, 640, 420));

        add(jLayeredPane2, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(54, 184, -1, -1));

        jPanel4.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(null, "WELCOME", javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.DEFAULT_JUSTIFICATION, javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.DEFAULT_POSITION, new java.awt.Font("Comic Sans MS", 1, 24), new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 153))); // NOI18N
        jPanel4.setLayout(new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteLayout());

        jLabel10.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Comic Sans MS", 1, 18)); // NOI18N
        jLabel10.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 153));
        jLabel10.setText("INSTRUCTION:");
        jPanel4.add(jLabel10, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(60, 80, -1, -1));

        jLabel11.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Comic Sans MS", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
        jLabel11.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 153));
        jLabel11.setText("1. You Will Have To Login With Correct Username,Password.");
        jPanel4.add(jLabel11, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(60, 150, 390, -1));

        jLabel12.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Comic Sans MS", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
        jLabel12.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 153));
        jLabel12.setText("2. If You Forget Your Password Press \"forgot Password?\".");
        jPanel4.add(jLabel12, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(60, 190, 380, -1));

        jLabel13.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Comic Sans MS", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
        jLabel13.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 153));
        jLabel13.setText("3. Then You Have To Give Your Correct Phone Number To ");
        jPanel4.add(jLabel13, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(60, 230, 390, -1));

        jLabel14.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Comic Sans MS", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
        jLabel14.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 153));
        jLabel14.setText("4. If You Sucessfully Logged In You Can Sell & Purchase ");
        jPanel4.add(jLabel14, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(60, 300, 380, -1));

        jLabel15.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Comic Sans MS", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
        jLabel15.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 153));
        jLabel15.setText(" Medicine From The Dispensary.");
        jPanel4.add(jLabel15, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(70, 330, -1, -1));

        jLabel16.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Comic Sans MS", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
        jLabel16.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 153));
        jLabel16.setText("Change Your Password.");
        jPanel4.add(jLabel16, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(80, 260, -1, -1));

        add(jPanel4, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(812, 184, 496, 420));

        jLabel17.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Comic Sans MS", 1, 12)); // NOI18N
        jLabel17.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 153));
        add(jLabel17, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(1250, 670, 107, 16));

        jLabel18.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Comic Sans MS", 1, 12)); // NOI18N
        jLabel18.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 153));
        add(jLabel18, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(1250, 660, 81, 13));
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        Connection conn=null;
        try{
                try {
                    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(Login.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }

            conn=DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL,USER,PASS);

            Statement stmt=conn.createStatement();
            String sql;
            String S=jTextField1.getText();
            String S1=jPasswordField1.getText();
            String S3=jComboBox1.getSelectedItem().toString();
            sql="SELECT * from user_pass where username='"+S+"' and password='"+S1+"' and type='"+S3+"'";
            ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery(sql);
            if(rs.next()){
                CardLayout layout=(CardLayout)contentpane.getLayout();
                //layout.show(contentpane, "Panel 2");
                layout.next(contentpane);
                jTextField1.setText("");
                jPasswordField1.setText("");
            }
            else JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invaild Username or Password");
            stmt.close();
            conn.close();



        }
        catch(SQLException se)
        {
            se.printStackTrace();
        }
    }                                        

    private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        Connection conn=null;
        try{
                try {
                    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(Login.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }

            conn=DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL,USER,PASS);

            Statement stmt=conn.createStatement();
            String sql;
            String S1=jTextField4.getText();
            phn=jTextField2.getText();
            sql="SELECT * from user_pass where Phone='"+phn+"'";
            ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery(sql);
            if(S1.equals("phoney Security")&&rs.next()){
                jPanel3.setVisible(false);
                jPanel1.setVisible(false);
                jPanel2.setVisible(true);
            }
            else JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Phone No didn't Match");

            stmt.close();
            conn.close();



        }
        catch(SQLException se)
        {
            se.printStackTrace();
        }
    }                                        

    private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        jPanel2.setVisible(false);
        jPanel3.setVisible(false);
        jPanel1.setVisible(true);
    }                                        

    private void jLabel6MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                     
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        jPanel1.setVisible(false);
        jPanel2.setVisible(false);
        jPanel3.setVisible(true);

    }                                    

    private void jButton4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        String S1=jPasswordField2.getText();
        String S2=jPasswordField3.getText();
        if(S1.equals(S2)){
            Connection conn=null;
            try{
                try {
                    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(Login.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }


                conn=DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL,USER,PASS);

                Statement stmt=conn.createStatement();
                String sql;

                sql="Update user_pass set Password='"+S1+"' where Phone='"+phn+"'";
                stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
                stmt.close();
                conn.close();
            }
            catch(SQLException se)
            {
                se.printStackTrace();
            }
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Password Changed");
                jPanel2.setVisible(false);
                jPanel3.setVisible(false);
                jPanel1.setVisible(true);
            }
            else JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Didn't Match");
    }                                        

    private void jButton5ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        jPanel2.setVisible(false);
        jPanel1.setVisible(false);
        jPanel3.setVisible(true);
    }                                        


    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton3;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton4;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton5;
    private javax.swing.JComboBox jComboBox1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel10;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel11;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel12;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel13;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel14;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel15;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel16;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel17;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel18;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel5;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel6;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel7;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel8;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel9;
    private javax.swing.JLayeredPane jLayeredPane2;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel2;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel3;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel4;
    private javax.swing.JPasswordField jPasswordField1;
    private javax.swing.JPasswordField jPasswordField2;
    private javax.swing.JPasswordField jPasswordField3;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField2;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField4;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

and this is the second card

```
public class Main extends Login {

    private JPanel contentPane;
    public int a;
    /**
     * Creates new form Main
     */
    public Main(JPanel cp) {
        super(cp);
        //super.name;
        //System.out.println(super.name);
        contentPane = cp;
        initComponents();


    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();

        jButton1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 18)); // NOI18N
        jButton1.setText("Back");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(this);
        this.setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(456, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jButton1)
                        .addGap(36, 36, 36))
                    .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 186, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGap(158, 158, 158))))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(20, 20, 20)
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addGap(87, 87, 87)
                .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(442, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        //jTextField1.setText(super.name);
        CardLayout layout=(CardLayout)contentPane.getLayout();
        layout.show(contentPane, "Panel 1");
        System.out.println(super.name);
    }                                        

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Here i want to pass the value name variable to the next panel

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I pass data between cards in Java CardLayout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14514912/how-do-i-pass-data-between-cards-in-java-cardlayout)

Comment: 1) Exactly what information are you trying to pass? 2) You've posted a lot of code, most of it completely unrelated to your main problem. Consider paring down your code to the bare minimum, one that requires no absolute layouts, one that requires no database access, but just enough code to run and demonstrate your problem, a [minimal example program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). 3) Your question really boils down to a) how do I pass information from one object to another (getters and setters work here), and b) how do I get notified when this transfer should occur.

Comment: Also, if you give your variables names that have meaning, your code will be a whole lot easier for others (and your future self) to understand. jButton4 has no meaning to us, but closeWindowButton does.

Comment: Also, you're misusing inheritance since the Main class should most definitely *not* inherit from the Login class. If you're doing this to try to get information from the Login class to the Main class, don't as that's not what inheritance is for, and this will lead to significant problems with your program.